# Apply filters on more than one field

Tags: qt, search, filter, qml

I have a model that has multiple fields, something like this

```
ListModel{
    id: targetModel
    ListElement{name: "entry"; field1: "entry"; field2: "entry"}
    etc.....
}
```

I am search through this model to find entries that have some target string, using:

```
property var searchInput: "string"
property var targetField: "Field1"

SortFilterProxyModel {
    id: searchFilterModel
    sourceModel: targetModel
    filters: AnyOf {
        RegExpFilter {
            roleName: targetField
            pattern: searchInput
            caseSensitivity: Qt.CaseInsensitive
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to search for all entries that have "searchInput" in either "Field1" or "Field2", or both. How do you do this?

EDIT for Reference below:

```
property var patternList: {["phrase1" ,"phrase2"]} 
SortFilterProxyModel { 
   id: search 
   sourceModel: targetModel
   filters: AnyOf { 
      RegExpFilter { 
         roleName: "rolename" 
         pattern: patternList[0] && patternList[1] 
         caseSensitivity: Qt.CaseInsensitive 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: what is `SortFilterProxyModel`?

Comment: Please share SortFilterProxyModel codesnippet. It helps to understand before answering to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have used [SortFilterProxyModel](https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel).

Add multiple filters under the AnyOf filter. If any of the filters inside AnyOf return true (ie. have a positive match), then that record will be returned by the model. If all of the filters under AnyOf return false, then that record will not be returned by the model.

```
SortFilterProxyModel {
    id: searchFilterModel
    sourceModel: targetModel
    // AnyOf will return the row if any of the filters
    // returns true (ie. matches)
    filters: AnyOf {
        // first field filter
        RegExpFilter {
            roleName: "field1"
            pattern: searchInput
            caseSensitivity: Qt.CaseInsensitive
        }
        // second field filter
        RegExpFilter {
            roleName: "field2"
            pattern: searchInput
            caseSensitivity: Qt.CaseInsensitive
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like what I want, but is there a way you can do this by iterating over "roleName" and "pattern"? In other words if the multiple inputs for these fields were different each time, and the number of them changed. Something like: roleName: ["role1", "role2"] and pattern: ["search1", "search2", "search3"]?

Comment: @Sam In the case where the roleNames can change dynamically, then I would use a Component { ... } for each RegExpFilter. When you change the roleNames or the patterns, then you can dynamically create the components with Component.createComponent({...}) passing the parameters for the roleName, pattern, etc. And then you assign the dynamically created filters to the searchFilterModel.filters property. You could also choose to look at the C++ side of SortFilterProxyModel and add some Q_PROPERTIES and do the above from C++.

Comment: If I do this (SEE CODE IN OP) it does exactly what I want, but I would need to change the "patternList" variable to an expression such as is entered in the "pattern" field. How would I do this?